# Order of comparison for heap elements in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, heap

I'm using a heap to make a priority queue using heapq.

I insert an item into the queue using

`heapq.heappush(h, (cost, node))`

where `h` is the heap object, `cost` is the item by which I order my heap and `node` is an object of a custom defined class.

When I run the code, I get the following error when I insert two different items in `h` with the same `cost`

> TypeError: unorderable types: SearchNode() < SearchNode()

where `SearchNode()` is the class of `node`

The error makes it clear that Python is comparing the second item.

**Is there an order of comparison for the heap elements?** If yes, how can I resolve ties in the algorithm such that it does not start comparing the second item. One possible solution that comes to my mind is to overload the comparison operators for the `SearchNode()` class.

I'm very new to python so feel free to point out if I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: for tuples, if the first element is equal (here `cost`), then comparison will be via the second variable (here `node`).

Comment: So you either need to make nodes comparable, or add a middle element for breaking ties that somehow is never tied itself (perhaps an incrementing value?)

Comment: @Rishav is there a way to prevent that second comparison? Can't heap store equal data like other data structures. Otherwise the suggestion by jonrsharpe seems a good enough workaround.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe suggests - this even has its own section in the [heapq documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes)... Otherwise, you'll need to make your `SearchNode` objects orderable by *something* as suggested by James in their answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can sensibly decide on a way to compare nodes, you could use this to break ties. For example, each node may be assigned a "label", which you can guarantee to be unique. You could break ties by comparing labels lexicographically.#

```
class SearchNode:
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        #etc

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.label < other.label
```

This would ensure that comparisons of `(cost, node)` is deterministic.

Answer (score 5):

Introduce a small class that doesn't include the node in the comparison:

```
class CostAndNode:
    def __init__(self, cost, node):
        self.cost = cost
        self.node = node

    # do not compare nodes
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cost < other.cost

h = []

heapq.heappush(h, CostAndNode(1, node1))
heapq.heappush(h, CostAndNode(1, node2))
```

Answer (score -2):

PQ with list and `bisect`, strings as stored objects for example. No changes in stored object required. Just construct `item = (cost, object)` and insert it in PQ.

```
import bisect
# PQ of items
PQ = [
    (10, 'aaa'),
    (30, 'cccc'),
    (40, 'dddd'),
]

def pq_insert(pq, item):
    keys = [e[0] for e in pq]
    i = bisect.bisect(keys, item[0])
    pq.insert(i, item)

e = (20, 'bbbb')
pq_insert(PQ, e)
```

Some REPL output

```
>>> print PQ
[(10, 'aaa'), (30, 'cccc'), (40, 'dddd')]
>>> e = (20, 'bbbb')
>>> pq_insert(PQ, e)
>>> print PQ
[(10, 'aaa'), (20, 'bbbb'), (30, 'cccc'), (40, 'dddd')]
>>>
```

Comment: How does this help the OP with their main problem that their node's *aren't* strings? Also - if you wanted to use `bisect` - there's `insort_*` methods that'll do most of your `pq_insert` anyway...

Comment: 1) you can always construct item from object. `item = ( cost, object)`     2) yes, you can use `insort_*`, but it should use comparable objects